# Pharo Smalltalk customizing font sizes, styles and backgrounds

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

Basically I am having 2 problems, I am trying to code a simple GUI using Pharo 4.0 Smalltalk. I am not able to change font size/style in pharo for my labels or text areas/button. I am also not able to change their background colors and border widths. I have tried all ways:

```
font1 := (TextFontReference toFont: 
                (StrikeFont familyName: 'Atlanta' size: 22)).
TextMorph  new contents: ('test' asText addAttribute: font1); 
color: Color blue; 
autoFit: true; 
borderColor: Color green; 
borderWidth: 2.

SimpleButtonMorph new target: self;
label: 'test1';
actionSelector: #test1click; 
basicBorderColor: Color green; 
basicBorderWidth: 2; 
highlightColor: Color green.

TextMorph  new contents: 'test2'; 
color: Color blue; 
autoFit: true; 
borderColor: Color green; 
borderWidth: 2; 
font:'Atlanta' / fontName: 'Atlanta' pointSize: 22 / fontName: 'Arial' size: 32.
```

None of the above options work. basically I need to customize my fonts and backgrounds for buttons and labels. How should I go about this?

Comment: Could you please make the code examples more explicit? What did you try, what did you expect as a result and it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

As for the background colors and border widths it works fine is you add `openInWorld` .

```
SimpleButtonMorph new target: self;
label: 'test1';
actionSelector: #test1click; 
basicBorderColor: Color green; 
basicBorderWidth: 2; 
highlightColor: Color green;
openInWorld
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The color should be a text attribute (TextColor) in a TextMorph, a font is not a text attribute (see class side of Text). Is Atlanta a StrikeFont or a truetype? StrikeFonts are the old bitmap fonts. For some simple code showing custom colors, fonts and borders, you might want to load CardsMorphic from the Configuration Browser